# Getting a table from wikipedia article from it's API

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I need to use the table in from this wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_visited_museums to make a database in python (though the latter part is irrelevant atm). I have to use the API (can't scrape) to access it. Right now I'm trying the API's documentation https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#Example_1:_Parse_content_of_a_page Example #2 from this page is exactly what I want to do, but it's returning an error, and even running the original code in my notebook it also returns an error. Can anyone tell me how to either alter that code so it runs, or direct me to another way to do the same thing? Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you scrape? It would be a lot easier than what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This fetches the content you're after: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=List%20of%20most%20visited%20museums&prop=wikitext&section=2&format=json

If the example isn't working in your notebook, the problem probably lies with the rest of your code and not with the API call.